# Try to have unique OpportunityLineItem APEX-CODE

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'm currently working on a trigger for  the OpportunityLineItem, every product on Salesforce are our "basic" products.

When a salesman will add a product to an opportunity he will also need to put the mpn ( = unique ID for a product) who will call our website to get the real price, because the real price depend of every option set on the product .
My trigger is calling a class to make the request, so far it's working!
But when i want to add the same couple of productID and mpn it will not work.

Problem:

The salesman will add a product  OpportunityLineItem , but this product is already in his current OpportunityLineItem  of his Opportunity so it will not work.

First, my trigger will not get the price because my SOQL request will return more than one result .

Here my trigger:

```
trigger GetRealPrice on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    for(OpportunityLineItem op : Trigger.new){
        RequestTest.getThePrice(op.Id_UAD__c,op.MPN__c,op.OpportunityId);  
    }
}
```

Here the called class;

```
public class RequestTest {
    //Future annotation to mark the method as async.
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void getThePrice(Decimal idUad, String mpnProduct,String opID){
        // Build the http request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://www.site.com/mpn.getprice?id='+idUad+'&mpn='+mpnProduct);
        req.setMethod('GET'); 

         String result;
         HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
         System.debug(res.getBody());
         result = res.getBody();
          Decimal price = Decimal.valueof(result);

         System.debug(opID);
         OpportunityLineItem op = [SELECT UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                                  WHERE Id_UAD__c = :idUad
                                  AND OpportunityId = :opID 
                                  AND MPN__c = :mpnProduct] ;
        System.debug('you went through step1');

        op.UnitPrice = price;
        System.debug('This is the opportunity price'+op.UnitPrice);
        update op;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping through each line item in the trigger, pass the line item ID.  Then change your method to handle the update per line item:

```
trigger GetRealPrice on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
  for(OpportunityLineItem op : Trigger.new){
    RequestTest.getThePrice(op.Id_UAD__c,op.MPN__c,op.Id);  
  }
}

...

public class RequestTest {
  //Future annotation to mark the method as async.
  @Future(callout=true)
  public static void getThePrice(Decimal idUad, String mpnProduct,String opLineID){
    ...
    Decimal price = Decimal.valueof(result);
    System.debug(opID);
    OpportunityLineItem op = [SELECT UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                              WHERE Id = :opLineID] ;

    op.UnitPrice = price;
    System.debug('This is the opportunity price'+op.UnitPrice);
    update op;
  }
}
```